# How to run nestjs app in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs

I am getting this error when I try to build from my docker container for a nestjs app

```
> node dist/main

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Here is the docker file.

```yaml
# Use multi-stage builds in order to prevent leaking tokens.
# First stage to build
FROM node:12.18.4-alpine3.12 AS build
ARG NPM_TOKEN

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# Second stage to run
FROM node:12.18.4-alpine3.12

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app /app

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

I am not sure why it throws this error as the `npm run start:prod` command seem to be working on my host machine.

Comment: did you change `webpack` configuration in `nest-cli.json`?

Comment: @AminTaghikhani no I did not

Comment: can you docker `exec` inside container and `ls` inside `dist` directory and check directory?

Comment: I'm using this Dockerfile and it's working fine: https://gist.github.com/LarsFlieger/580112a6dc30f3881d9d8f0756470d5c

Maybe try to check if the WORKDIR is correct.